# operator std::string() const?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

Can somebody tell me what precisely

```
operator std::string()
```

stands for?

Answer (score 34):

It is a [conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) that allows the object to be explicitly or implicitly casted to std::string. When such a cast occurs, the operator is invoked and the result of the cast is the result of the invocation.

As an example of an implicit cast, suppose you had a function that accepted type `std::string` or `const std::string&`, but not the given object type. Passing your object to that function would result in the conversion operator being invoked, with the result passed to the function instead of your type.

Answer (score 21):

It is a cast operator. Any class that defines this type can be used anywhere a `std::string` is required. For instance,

```
class Foo {
public:
    operator std::string() const { return "I am a foo!"; }
};
...
Foo foo;
std::cout << foo; // Will print "I am a foo!".
```

Cast operators are almost always a bad idea, since there is invariably a better way to achieve the same result. In the above case, you are better off defining `operator<<(std::ostream&, const Foo&)`.

Comment: I object to the term "always", it is too absolute. I think "usually" would be a better term.

Comment: Martin, I didn't say "always". I said "almost always" which isn't absolute, and is, IMO, closer to the truth than "usually".

Comment: Loki, your own comment is too absolute.  Should one *always* avoid the term "always", or should one *usually* avoid the term "always"?

Comment: things are getting paradoxical

Comment: dont you need to typecast foo to (string)foo ?

Comment: @poorva: No, it's an implicit cast. In C++11 you can write `explicit operator std::string() …` to require an explicit cast.

Comment: @poorva you are correct, @MarceloCantos you are wrong: you do need to cast it explicitly to string in this case, otherwise you'll get an error `error: cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&` 

The reason for that is the `operator<<` is defined as a template function, so you must have exact match for its arguments, and the implicit cast is not relevant.

Comment: Please note that the code in this answer (`std::cout << foo;`) simply **won't compile**, because as @EranMarom noted `operator<<` is a template function. I tried. The compiler (g++ 7.3, c++14) said `error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'Foo')`.