# How can I use stringstream as a parameter for a c++ function?

Tags: c++, string, function, concatenation, stringstream

I was looking for solutions to appending strings with other primitives and found that stringstream was the easiest solution.  However, I wanted to streamline the process so I wanted to make a function to ease its use.  In case you are proposing alternate methods for concatenation, i need the final result to be char*.  I used a loop (i) with:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "test" << i;      
char* name = new char[ss.str().size() + 1];//allocate
strcpy(name, ss.str().c_str());//copy and put (char*)c_str in name
```

So the output is something link test1test2test3...  This was the most reasonable solution I could muster.  I was trying to put it into a function for ease of use, but am running into problems. I wanted to do something like:

```
char* string_to_pointer( char* dest, std::stringstream* _ss ) {
   char* result = new char[_ss->str().size() + 1];
   strcpy(result, _ss->str().c_str());
   return result;
}
```

I could then do something like:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "test" << i;      
char* name = string_to_pointer( name, &ss );
```

I'm pretty new to c++ and this seems like the correct use syntactically, but I am running into runtime issues and would welcome solutions on how to get this in an easy to use function without resulting to Boost.

Comment: Did you try it out?

EDIT: What are your runtime issues?

Comment: Why do you need to do the "string_to_pointer" conversion? And are you sure that you want the final result to be 'char *' ? If it is final, then there is no need to modify it anymore, so maybe const char *? That way you could continue and use stringstream till the very end.

Comment: string_to_pointer is weird: it doesn't use its first parameter.

Comment: I don't really see a purpose for this function...you use strings and stringstreams so you can avoid stuff like strcpy

Comment: Thank you for your replies.  I ended up going an entirely different route and I think this was just a case of me trying 100s of things and getting the issue even more confused.  From all your responses I noticed a lot of things wrong with my question, thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `std::stringstream::str()` function to retrieve the contents of the string.

Example:

```
int foo = 42;
double bar = 12.67;

std::stringstream ss;
ss << "foo bar - " << foo << ' ' << bar;

std::string result = ss.str();
```

If you dont want to modify the string further, you can now simple call `result.c_str()` to acquire a `const char*`. However, if you really need a modifyable `char*` you have to copy the contents of the string to a cstring:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> cstring = new char[result.size() + 1];
strcpy(cstring.get(), result.c_str());
```

Comment: The solution I came upon is very similar to your second code block.  I am having trouble condensing that block into an easy to use function.  Something like: `char* myFunc( char* dest, stringstream ss)` or `char* myFunc( char* dest, string s)`.   To be specific: `Error 5 error C3867: 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::c_str': function call missing argument list; use '&std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::c_str' to create a pointer to member
`

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

class ToString {
  std::ostringstream stream;
public:
  template<typename T>
  inline ToString &operator<<(const T&val) {
    stream << val;
    return *this;
  }

  inline operator std::string() const {
    return stream.str();
  } 
};
```

You can use it like this:

```
std::string str = ToString() << "Test " << 5 << " and " << 4.2;
```

Comment: For those like me who have never seen `inline operator std::string() const` as a member function, this is called a [user-defined conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator). I found it mentioned in [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044690/operator-stdstring-const).

Answer (score 0):

```
char* string_to_cstring ( const std::string &_ss )
```

Would be cleaner! Use with `string_to_cstring(ss.str())`

Need the returned C-String to be changeble? Because if not, just use `ss.str().c_str()` wherever you need it!

Or use:

```
char* result = new char[ss.str().size() + 1] (); // value initialized
ss.str().copy(result,std::string::npos);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, very concise