# How to use the overloaded "operator<<" properly?

Tags: c++

There is a template class in c++:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::ostream;
using std::vector;

template<typename T>
class Business {
public:

    // default constructor
    Business() {
        customers.push_back(0);
    }

    // value constructor
    Business(vector<T> vec) {

        for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
            customers.push_back(vec[i]);
    }

    T getInfo(int i) const {
        if (i < 0 ) return 0;
        else return customers[i];
    }

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const Business<T> &b) {

        std::string message = "";
        for (int i=0 ; i<b.customers.size() ; ++i) {
            message += b.getInfo(i) + " ";
        }
        return os << message;
    }

private:
    vector<T> customers;
};
```

But I receive the following error about the `operator<<` body:

`error: invalid operands to binary expression:  message += b.getInfo(i) + " ";`

After receiving that error, I changed the errorprone line of code to:

`message += b.getInfo(i)`

But then the error was:

`error: no viable overloaded '+=': message += b.getInfo(i)`

**Edit:**
There is a main class in which I have:

```cpp
Business<Merchant<95>> bu({45, 87, 95, 23});
std::cout << bu << endl;
```

where `Merchant<95>` is a another template class.

The error I receive is follows by:

`in instantiation of member function 'operator<<' requested here: cout << bu << endl;`

I wonder how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: `std::string`'s `+=` operator only works with other strings. if `T` is not a `std::string` or something implicitly convertible to `std::string` you should receive a message like this.

Comment: @user4581301 What other options can I use?

Comment: At the moment I could be misdiagnosing. I can't currently reproduce your problem.

Comment: @user4581301 I reckon you are right, can I use anyother thing instead of string type in `std::string message = "";` and then take string out of it?

Comment: I need to see more of what you are doing. To get the reported error message there should be a couple other error messages along with it. I also forgot `+=` can accept `char`s and integer data types are implicitly convertible to `char`s. No error message in that case, just a wrong answer. Could you update the question with a [mcve] (assuming making the [mcve] doesn't lead to a "D'oh!" moment and you fixing the bug)?

Comment: What is `T`? Also, as to your other question, your options are usually `std:string`, `char*`, possibly `char` (maybe), and possibly `int` (also maybe).

Comment: Also anything with `operator std::string()` might be okay here.

Comment: I'm still looking at this wrong. an integer plus a string literal is going to be pointer arithmetic an offset into that string literal. Example: https://ideone.com/iCsUEX . `"ABC"` is a `const char[4]`. It decays to a `const char *`, the address of the `"ABC"` in memory. If you add 1 to that address you basically have a string "BC". But now I'm wandering off into babble-land. I think I should stop for the night.

Comment: @user4581301 I edited the question, please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: @user4581301 By the way I found somewhere else on the stackoverflow that: _For most standard types of T you can use a stringstream ss; and ss << value (where value is type T) then get the string from ss_ , what do you think about it?

Comment: The key there is *standard types*. `Merchant`, whatever it is, isn't standard. You should also have a problem with `if (i < 0 ) return 0;` unless you have a method that transforms the `int` 0 into a `Merchant`. We still need more. Please read [mcve] for more information on what we need.

Comment: Where is the function that (implicitly?) converts `Merchant<95>` to `std::string`? I advise working on that sub-problem before returning to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all people who spent time to solve the question, I just needed to change the body of the `for loop` inside `friend ostream &operator<<`. Therefore, the correct way is as follows:

```cpp
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const Business<T> &b) {
        for (int i=0 ; i<b.customers.size() ; ++i) {
            os << b.getInfo(i);
        }
        return os;
}
```

Comment: To also print out the space use `os << b.getInfo(i) << ' ';`

Answer (score 1):

I could not provide a fix without looking at your `Merchant` class template. I can tell what the issue is,

When you instantiate a `Business` with `Merchant`, the `T` in your class template is replaced with a `Merchant`. The compiler stamps out a `Business<Merchant>` that will have a member function like the following, among other things,

```
   Merchant getInfo(int i) const {
        if (i < 0 ) return 0;
        else return customers[i];
    }
```

As you can see, `getInfo` returns a `Merchent` (the returned `T` is replaced with `Merchent`). 
Now this is where the problem creeps in. Consider the following now,

```
        std::string message = "";
        for (int i=0 ; i<b.customers.size() ; ++i) {
            message += b.getInfo(i) + " ";
        }
```

In `message += b.getInfo(i);`, `message` is of type `string` and `b.getInfo(i)` returns a `Merchant` as we saw before. The compiler doesn't know how to convert a `Merchant` to `string` to add it to `message`. Thus is throws a `no match for 'operator+='`.

A fix would to be tell the compiler how to convert a `Merchant` to a string explicit. This requires defining `operator std::string()` in `Merchant`.

It might look like so,

```
Merchant<T>{
    ...
    public:
         operator std::string() const { 
             return to_string(MerchantID)+... }
    ...
};
```

This depends on your `Merchant` and the primitive types that is has within. See [operator std::string() const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044690/operator-stdstring-const).

Comment: Few too many guesses for my tastes, but lets see where this goes.

Comment: Thank you @rranjik and @user4581301 and also the rest of people helped above, I apprecieate your help, I found the answer, inside the `friend ostream &operator<<` and inside the loop, I just needed to put `os << b.getInfo(i)` and then return os. It works now!

Answer (score 1):

The error you are receiving is related to the type (class) that you are instantiating the template on -- *Merchant* in your main example --, not the template class *Bussiness* itself.

Make sure that you have defined a function within Merchant to convert it to a string, or even char const*, and your code will compile.